# How do I check if a sequence exists or not in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sequence

I am using Oracle 11g. I want to be able to determine whether a particular sequence exists or not. I have tried the code below but it is not working. (It is returning 0 as count value when there should be more):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM user_sequences
WHERE sequence_name = 'SCHEMA.SEQUENCE_NAME';
```

If anyone knows why this is, please help me.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you are running the query as user `MP` then try it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM user_sequences 
WHERE sequence_name = 'SEQ_SSO_KEY_AUTHENTICATION';
```

else, try it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM all_sequences 
WHERE sequence_name = 'SEQ_SSO_KEY_AUTHENTICATION'
AND sequence_owner = 'MP' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, keep in mind that you may not be granted to see all sequences in DB.
In this case scripts provided above may not work, and you should run something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DBA_SEQUENCES;
```

But this also may not work if you have no access to DBA_SEQUENCES view.

Check [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2053.htm).

Answer (score 1):

For newer/11g versions, the following query works. One suggestion, I couldn't initially make it work because I was using lowercase letters for sequence names. Making it all caps returned expected value

```
SELECT * FROM all_objects ao WHERE ao.owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME' AND ao.OBJECT_TYPE ='SEQUENCE' 
AND ao.OBJECT_NAME ='CAPITAL_SEQ_NAME';
```